# fluentd assigning types to new field in filter

Tags: ruby, filter, fluentd

I'm using fluentd to push some data from a set of sensors. The data i'm pushing contain a "timestamp" field (in millisecs) that I need to explode in its date components (year, month, etc etc). I'm using a filter to do that when data are pushed, so that through some ruby code I can easily explode the timestamp, e.g.

```
<filter *>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby
  <record>
    year ${Time.at(Integer(record['timestamp'])/1000.0).strftime("%Y")}
    monthnumber ${Time.at(Integer(record['timestamp'])/1000.0).strftime("%-m")}
    monthname ${Time.at(Integer(record['timestamp'])/1000.0).strftime("%B")}
    daynumber ${Time.at(Integer(record['timestamp'])/1000.0).strftime("%-d")}
    dayname ${Time.at(Integer(record['timestamp'])/1000.0).strftime("%A")}
    hour ${Time.at(Integer(record['timestamp'])/1000.0).strftime("%-k")}
    minutes ${Time.at(Integer(record['timestamp'])/1000.0).strftime("%-M")}
    seconds ${Time.at(Integer(record['timestamp'])/1000.0).strftime("%-S")}
  </record>
</filter>
```

my problem is that the new fields it is gonna incorporate in the json are assigned with string types, while for some of the I strictly need integers (for example, for the year, monthnumber, daynumber, etc). It there any way to tell fluentd that these field must be added as integers?

I tried with:

```
year ${Integer(Time.at(Integer(record['timestamp'])/1000.0).strftime("%Y"))}
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation here](http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/filter_record_transformer#example-configurations), you can use the option `auto_typecast true` that will assign the type defined inside the Ruby code for every field.